# (Apache) Possible to match UTF8 characters in rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I know it's possible to create links where UTF8 characters are encoded, but is it possible to actually match those characters within rewrite rules? Example being just rewrite a static page in utf8 cyrillic russian text to some other page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it’s possible:

```
RewriteRule ^de/b\xC3\xA4ume$ en/trees [L]
```

This will match `/de/bäume` and rewrite it to `/en/trees`.

Comment: Interesting. And one must convert the % to \x. I just can't get it to work the other way. Since there is no regex happening there, I'm assuming I can keep the % chars.